# Is it possible to access DOM elements of a chrome app from another chrome app / extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

This is something like a chrome extension changes the elements of a web page dynamically.

I am wondering if i can change the DOM elements of a chrome app from another chrome app or extension.

If this is possible, how can I do that ?

========================================================

Example:

There is a standalone chrome app working on the desktop

There is another app / extension works like a chrome app debugging tool which can access the content of that standalone app

Comment: can you give us a practical example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be no, since when you are saying the DOM elements of a chrome extension, I guess you mean the popup/options page for the extension, its url starts with `chrome://extensions` while content script can't access this kind of page.

The answer can also be yes, since if you have control on both of the extension, you can do [Cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external), in this way, to some degree you can achieve change the DOM of a chrome extension from another extension.